# Convert list to map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

Using Java 1.5 how can I convert the following list structure to a nested map:

`List<CsSectionDetail> list` to `Map<Integer,Map<Integer, List<CsSectionDetail>>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Map<Integer,List<CsSectionDetail>>>();`

The above list contains two keys **mainTaskId** and **subTaskId** which should be converted to the above map structure with **first Integer mainTaskId** and **second Integer subTaskId**.

I already have a function to convert `List<CsSectionDetail>` list to map , with the structure `Map<Integer, List<CsSectionDetail>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<CsSectionDetail>>();`
Below is the code

```
public Map<Integer, List<CsSectionDetail>> getCsSectionDetail4Display(List<CsSectionDetail> list, boolean groupByMainTaskOnly) {
        Map<Integer, List<CsSectionDetail>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<CsSectionDetail>>();

        Iterator<CsSectionDetail> it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
            CsSectionDetail csDetail = (CsSectionDetail) it.next();
            add2Map(csDetail, map, groupByMainTaskOnly);
    }
    return map;
    }

private void add2Map(CsSectionDetail csDetail, Map<Integer, List<CsSectionDetail>> map, boolean groupByMainTaskOnly) {
       List<CsSectionDetail> list;
        Integer key; 

        if (groupByMainTaskOnly) {
            key = csDetail.getProjectTaskId().getId();
        } else {
            if (csDetail.getProjectSubTaskId() == 0) {
                key = csDetail.getProjectTaskId().getId();
            } else {
                key = new Integer(csDetail.getProjectSubTaskId());
            }
        }
        list = (List<CsSectionDetail>) map.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<CsSectionDetail>();
        }
```

How can modify the above code to get the nested map structure?

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Your add2Map function creates a list as the value of the map. Instead, create a map, and put in that map the subTaskId as the key and the CsSectionDetail as the value.

Comment: Is vanilla Java a requirement? I can post an answer in Guava if it helps. Would help if you post the methods of `CsSectionDetail` that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut your code in two methods for clarity, each filling the map at a different level:

```
private void add2TaskMap(CsSectionDetail csDetail, Map<Integer, Map<Integer,CsSectionDetail>> map) {
    Map<Integer,CsSectionDetail> submap;
     Integer key = csDetail.getProjectTaskId().getId();

     submap =map.get(key);
     if (submap == null) {
         submap = new HashMap<Integer,CsSectionDetail>();
         map.put(key, submap);
     }
     add2SubTaskMap(csDetail, submap);
}

private void add2SubTaskMap(CsSectionDetail csDetail, Map<Integer,CsSectionDetail> map) {
     Integer key;
     if (csDetail.getProjectSubTaskId() == 0) {
         key = csDetail.getProjectTaskId().getId();
     } else {
         key = new Integer(csDetail.getProjectSubTaskId());
     }

     map.put(key, csDetail);
}
```